# PHP DOMDocument/LIBXML replaces ( " and ' )

Tags: php, domdocument, libxml2

I'm trying to manipulate some sourcecode inside my WordPress plugin and have the issue that DOMDocument manipulates some strings and chars where it's not nessessary. Primary I only want to add some sourcecode on a specific id.

Thats the sourcecode:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->xmlStandalone = false;
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$doc->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
// Add some HTML Divs and CSS classes
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Original Sourcecode (WordPress):

```
<title>WordPress &#8211; Development &#8211; </title>
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin rel='preconnect' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://localhost/WordPress/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

After the DOMDocument routine:

```
<title>WordPress &ndash; Development &ndash; </title>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s.w.org">
<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin rel="preconnect">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="dashicons-css" href="http://localhost/WordPress/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.6" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Primary my problem are that he replaces some ' with ", removes "/"...

Hope anyone can help me. :-)

Comment: Are these changes breaking anything? It seems like the HTML should work just fine either way.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem...

With different themes it raises errors, sometimes doesn't run JS correctly or interprete inline codes false cause ("/').

Comment: Strange, the output is HTML5 compliant. Is it breaking only for Very Old Browsers? Is it maybe breaking because of some unrelated HTML error somewhere else, which gets triggered by this? Are the "different themes" doing regex on the output that breaks if it's not exactly as they think it should be?

Comment: DOMDocument doesn't save the source code, it parses it into a DOM structure. So it doesn't remember whether the input used single or double quotes, they both produce the same structure. When you later save it, it produces a canonical format.

Comment: It sounds like the application you're sending the output to expects XHTML, not HTML5. See http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#109416 for a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your application breaks when there's no `/>` at the end of the `<link` tag, it sounds like it requires XHTML rather than HTML. There's a [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#109416) in the PHP documentation that shows how to get `DOMDocument` to save XHTML, by using its `saveXML()` method instead.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument("1.0");
$doc->xmlStandalone = false;
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$doc->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
// Add some HTML Divs and CSS classes
$html = $doc->saveHTML($doc->doctype);
$html .= "\n";
$html .= $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I did not manage to do it with the XHTML method, even though it gave me new insights.

In short, maybe another question, what other possibility would there be? I would like to include a small PHP Snipped in the already loaded website.

I have a WordPress plugin which should output the text from a textarea according to a special CSS ID.

Javascript is not a solution (but used for fallback).